# Spring boot doesn't generate the table schema

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am new to spring. When I launch application, it start very well, but it doesn't generate the table schemas. I do not know if I made a mistake or if there is a configuration to do

SpringBootApplication

```
package org.opendevup;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TpSpringMvcApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TpSpringMvcApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_sco_mvc
spring.datasource.username=******
spring.datasource.password=******
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
server.port = 3647
```

Entity

```
package org.opendevup.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
public class Etudiant implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String nom;
    private Date dateNaissance;
    private String email;
    private String photo;

    public Etudiant() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Etudiant(String nom, Date dateNaissance, String email, String photo) {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.dateNaissance = dateNaissance;
        this.email = email;
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public Date getDateNaissance() {
        return dateNaissance;
    }

    public void setDateNaissance(Date dateNaissance) {
        this.dateNaissance = dateNaissance;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

}
```

Note: I have changed port of Tomcat because port 8080 is used by another process, and I have already created database : **db_sco_mvc**.

I am using maven for dependencies.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a table and a schema, do the following:

Add `@Entity`, implement the Serializable interface and create default and all-arguments constructor for you entity object.

In `application.properties`, use this config:

```
# Mysql
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://myurl/myschema?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass

# Hibernate
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i have same issue,it's didn't generate shema

Comment: Have you deleted the previously generated schema/database?

Comment: Yee i did delete

Comment: I note that @Entity is depreciated

Comment: Which `@Entity` are you using?
You should use `javax.persistence.Entity`

Answer (score 0):

Also add below config in you application:

`spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true`

for ddl-auto, you can keep using update or try the create-drop

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop`